# Media Encoder w\ Merge Files & SandyBridge Hardware Encoding Support

Tags: encoding, media, sandy-bridge

So i have a Z68 chipset that allows Quick Sync encoding on my i7 processor.

I want a media encoder that supports both Hardware encoding and allows me to "merge files".

My problem is Fraps breaks my recording into 4GB files.  I need to stitch these files together & re-encode for Youtube ect, but i want to use the hardware encoding I paid for.

I have not figured out how to do this on Handbrake or MediaEsspresso.